# How can i create an Azure Function in visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions

I am trying to create an Azure Function to publish to Azure in Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise , but when i try to create new Project i dont see an option for Azure Function (the lightning bolt). 
I have tried to install templates from nuget ... no luck 
Any ideas ?

Comment: Please check if you have installed "Azure development" in your vs2019, click "Tools" --> "Get Tools and Features" and install it, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPL6R.png) screenshot.

Comment: Yes i have installed that ..I have Azure Development, ASP.NET and web development , and .NET desktop environment.   I have even totally uninstalled VS2019 and re-installed. The service im dealing with  is in .net core 3.1 and i cant run it with vs2017, hence had to upgrade to vs2019. But  i cant even create new azure functions , unless it is something else ??

Comment: Did you follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio) to install vs2019 and "Azure development" ?

Comment: And may I know the version of your vs2019 ?

Comment: vs2019 enterprise Version 16.5.4

Comment: Ye i followed the tutorial mentioned above. When i enter functions in the search box , i get nothing. I even went to Install more tools and features .. unticked Azure Development and re-selected it .. still no luck ..    I also went to the menu in VS and selected Manage Extensions. I see the option in the Roaming Extension Manager . But i cant download . The only option is Stop Roaming . what is that ??

Comment: I'm afraid can not provide you more suggestions, you may get support on this [page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=5e4af7f3-a372-88ed-13a8-435150045599).

Comment: yes. but in mean time looks like i will be reverting back to vs 2017

Comment: WHat nuget package did you install ? Do you have rerference to any documentation that you followed and not seeing the desired behavior ? Can you add those details ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I rebooted into safe mode with networking to try and ignore all policies , it seemed to work. Hope it helps others –

Answer (score 0):

While installing Visual studio need to **check** under workloads **Azure Development** checkbox, which enables things like Azure Function, Azure WebJob templates for creating project locally. If Visual studio is already installed without Azure Development option we can still enable by navigating to New Project, scroll bottom to Install more tools and features which prompts Visual studio installer and provides you options to add or remove specific features of Visual studio.

Comment: I have as suggested by Hury earlier. no liuck

Comment: @Debbie.S while creating New Project, under platform are you seeing Azure as option in drop down? If yes can you select and let us know after selecting what project templates you are able to see?

Comment: After reinstalling component Azure Development, There is a log and it displays the following ,   Package 'msodbcsql,version=16.0.62003.5180,chip=x64,language=en-US' failed to install.  This installation is forbidden by system policy. Contact your system administrator..  Any help with adjusting system policy .. I am using windows 10 Home edition

Comment: It seems that there is some policy on your machine block the Installer to install the MSI packages.
Can you tell me if you have corporate policy or elevated AV policies in place blocking the VS install or can you check it with your system administrator and gain permissions to install these packages?
Refer below link
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/988299/error-1625-microsoftintellitraceprofilerproxymsi.html

Comment: how to check for corporate policy or elevated AV policies  ??? the second option in the link i have done and no difference .